# What is the meaning of /etc (as acronym)

Tags: etc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does etc stand for?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5665/what-does-etc-stand-for)

What does it mean? All I can think is *etcetera*. By my teacher told me that there is a more appropriate meaning.