# Why does mtab live in etc?

Tags: linux, filesystems, standard

Something I've never understood with linux is why a status file is stored under /etc.  As far as I know /etc/ is for configuration (relatively static) configuration files.  But `/etc/mtab` shows the current status of mounts on the system.

Under debian this has even been replaced with a symbolic link to `../proc/self/mounts` (ie: `/proc/self/mounts`).  This is actually important because with the creation of mount namespaces different processes can see different mounts.

Is there a particular historic reason for this and is there a good reason why it has not been removed entirely (in favor of `/proc/self/mounts`)?

Comment: Relating also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5665/117549

Comment: "is there a good reason why it has not been removed entirely" compatibility.